# Is keyof typeof right way to make type from enums list in typescript

Tags: typescript

```
enum StateEnum {
  processed = 'processed',
  inProgress = 'inProgress',
}

type StateType = StateEnum.processed | StateEnum.inProgress
```

Earlier I was creating type from `enum` list as you can see above , but each time when something change in my `enum` ( add some new key) , I have to go to my type and add it , and this is anoying . I've started to find out how to make it easier and found solution

```
type StateType = keyof typeof StateEnum
```

But I don't like it , it seems hacky to me . Is there any better way to make it ?

Comment: It's the way to do it according to the documentation, so I doubt you'll find a better way. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#enums-at-compile-time

Comment: With `enum State` there’s already a type named `State` equivalent to the union of all the enum value types.  So redefining it is a compiler error, and seems redundant anyway.  Could you provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE?

Comment: @jcalz changed names to show where is enum and where is type , I don''t have issue , I just want to know is there any other way to make what I wanted to achieve

Comment: Can you articulate the difference between the type `StateType` and the type `StateEnum`?  The former looks like a manual redefinition of the latter.  The type `StateEnum` is already a union of the value types of the enum object. Your definition is therefore redundant; you could write `type StateType = StateEnum` and nothing would change.  Maybe this is what you’re asking, actually: yes you can do it another way, and in fact, this other way happens automatically.  Does that make sense?

Comment: oh, yes , tried it and it works , instaed of making what I've done, you can just use enum as type and it works @jcalz , thanks for you answed , didn't know it

Comment: Okay I can write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

In the following [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html), all the members are *literals* (in your case, `string` [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html)):

```
enum StateEnum {
  processed = 'processed',
  inProgress = 'inProgress',
}
```

That makes `StateEnum` a [*union enum*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#union-enums-and-enum-member-types) where the type named `StateEnum` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all the members of the enum.

That means there's no need to manually define `StateType` to be such a union.  Indeed, if you use the quick info from an IntelliSense-enabled IDE to inspect `StateType`, you'll see that the compiler considers it to be equivalent:

```
type StateType = StateEnum.processed | StateEnum.inProgress;
// type StateType = StateEnum
```

So you might as well just use `StateEnum` as a type, as it automatically is the union type you're looking for.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/KYOwrgtgBAygLgQzsAouaBvAUFXUAOATgPYDGwAzhcACZQC8UA5EWZdTUwDQ54CWIAAokA5oXYNmA4cTHtuWAL5YsAG2BwoANwSqAXLETI0kANxYdqyfCSp0AOmmjxVU1AD07qMQDWCAJ4WutZGdpD2rORUtG6e3n6BKnD++MCGtgAqKWmMNsYOkey0UAA+6fnhTrIuFOZxyanlwFmNuaEmEEA)